# SQL Statement Executed In Java Messing With Date Format

Tags: java, sql, string, date, sqlite

Good morning. I have encountered a very interesting problem while executing an SQL-statement.
What I am trying to achieve: A date should be inserted into  a database as a string along with an integer.

```
try {
    DBHelper.st.execute("INSERT INTO days VALUES('"
        + date + "'," + num + ");");
} catch (SQLException xc) {
    xc.printStackTrace();
}
```

The connection with the database is working flawlessly and the two variables are inserted into the database.
However, the String date seems to be altered in the process.

```
String date = "2018-04-11";
```

When executing a query to the database (in SQLite3) afterwards the result looks as follows:

> 2003 | 1

Has anyone here experienced this before?

Comment: Consider using query parameters instead of gluing variable contents directly into your SQL. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: If you interpret 2018-04-11 as an arithmetic expression involving two subtractions, the result is 2003.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I can't see why the format should be the cause of the problem since it is saved as a String or - in SQL - varchar anyway.

Comment: @oleV.V. That is an excellent observation! Guessing somewhere in the code unintentionally an arithmic operation is performed. I am going to double check that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What columns do you have in you "days" table? Can you show the table definition? And yes, I'll repeat what has been already said, it's always better to use prepared queries with parameters.